# Why is my internet suddenly real slow?

Tags: internet, connection

My internet connection gives up to 50Mbps, and usually give 3 to 10 mbps and now it has been less than 0.5 for two nights in a row. I am sharing my phones internet connection with my computer - so wireless connection. Any thoughts what might be the cause?

Comment: Are you tethering to the phone?

Comment: No, I am tethering from my phone. It is cellphone contract with internet connection that I am sharing from my phone to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest plugging a network cable directly from your modem (supplied by ISP) into a computer and running a speed test (I use speedtest dot net), bypassing any other network equipment. If you get your full speed there, work your way back from modem to router, switch, extender if you have them, to determine which piece of equipment is causing the issue.

If you get the same slow speed at the modem, call your provider to supply another modem, or purchase your own if you are allowed by them to do so.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is tethering... but there's not exactly a wealth of information in the question.

Comment: Sure is, I totally missed that part.